# ASP.NET , How to break out from OnClick Without Refresh Page

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

I have an asp button that export sql query result to excel. If excel export is successful , Page never refresh . That's ok. But , If I get mistake When querying database then code throws exception and refresh page.

```
        protected void exportexcelmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataBaseConnector db = new DataBaseConnector("M");
        var masterid = Request.Form["MasterID"];

        try
        {

            db.Connect();
            db.InitCommand();
            db.SetSqlString(Procedures.ReportsCustomerEmail.ToString());
            db.AddParameter("@aysid", masterid);
            dt = db.ExecWithTable();
            db.Close();


            MyFunction.ExportExcel_Click(dt, "MyExcel");
        }

         catch (ThreadAbortException exp)
        {

                    //THAT is OK.Page never Refresh 

        }


        catch (SqlException exp)
        {

            if (db != null)
            {
                db.Close();
            }


             string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + exp.Message.Replace("'", "") + "');</script>";
             ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
             //PAGE REFRESH HERE
        }



        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            if (db != null)
            {
                db.Close();
            }
             string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + exp.Message.Replace("'", "") + "');</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);





        }
```

MyFunction.ExportExcel_Click(dt, "MyExcel")  creates excel and Finish with Responce.End() than throws ThreadAbortException . This part is OK. If I get database error , code throws SqlException , than page is refresh. **How to prevent page reload**

Comment: Have u tried with_ ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);

Comment: @MarcusHöglund , Yes I have tried , İt is same